# MySQL: Select several rows based on several keys on a given column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this mysql table structure:

```
------------------------------------
| item_id | meta_key | meta_value |
------------------------------------
159         category    Bungalow
159         location    Lagos
159         price       45000

160         category    Bungalow
160         location    Abuja
160         price       53500
...
350         category    Bungalow
350         location    Lagos
350         price       32000
```

What I'd like to do is select several rows matching two or more criteria based on the `meta_key` column. For example, say I wanted to select the `item_id` for every 'Bungalow' located in 'Lagos'. How would I go about doing that?

Here's my attempt, which is not working:

```
SELECT `item_id` FROM `item_meta`
WHERE 
`meta_key` = 'category' AND `meta_value` = 'Bungalow'
AND 
`meta_key` = 'location' AND `meta_value` = 'Lagos'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find the records matching with both the criteria here is a way of doing it

```
select `item_id` FROM `item_meta`
where 
( `meta_key` = 'category' and `meta_value` = 'Bungalow' )
or
( `meta_key` = 'location' AND `meta_value` = 'Lagos' )
group by `item_id` having count(*)=2
```

Comment: why having count(*)=2 ??

Comment: @Abhik, thanks for that. You understand what I need. Could you clarify for me the part of `having count(*)=2`? Any specific reason why the `=2`?

Comment: Having `count(*)=2` will ensure after `group by` that the returned `item_id` is from both the conditions. If you run the query without group by and having you can see it will return either 2 or 1 row for each matching `item_id` and we need only which are matching both hence group by and having.

Answer (score 0):

**Try as below with brackets otherwise you will not get expected result :**

```
SELECT `item_id` FROM `item_meta`
WHERE 
(`meta_key` = 'category' AND `meta_value` = 'Bungalow')
OR 
(`meta_key` = 'location' AND `meta_value` = 'Lagos')
```

Comment: see my comment on Ameya's answer below. The solution I'm looking for is NOT an EITHER...OR: `category== 'Bungalow' || 'location' == 'Lagos'`. I am looking for an inclusive solution: `'category' == Bungalow && location == Lagos`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to independently select by the 2 properties you are interested in. By joining the table with itself you can find the entries (by item_id) that share the 2 parameters.

Something along the lines of the following:

```
select category.item_id 
from item_meta category 
    join item_meta location on location.item_id = category.item_id
where location.meta_key = 'location' AND location.meta_value = 'Lagos'
    and category.meta_key = 'category' AND category.meta_value = 'Bungalow'
group by category.item_id
```